# Ajax is passing the data in the URL and doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i'm trying to pass some data with ajax but isn't working.

I do it before and it works i think it's something about cache.

I have this view:

```
@extends('cms.public.layouts.default')
@section('content')
<div class="col-md-10">
    <h3 style="letter-spacing:40px;text-align:center;color:f15d5e;">PROYECTOS</h3>
</div>

<div id="listall"> <!-- DIV TO LIST ALL THE PROJECTS START HERE -->
        <div class="col-md-2" style="padding:20px;">
          <button type="button" id="buttoncreate" class="btn btn-danger">Crear Proyecto</button>

        </div>
                      <table class="table">
                  <thead style="color:white">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Id</th>
                      <th>Slug</th>
                      <th>Order</th>
                      <th>Public</th>
                      <th>Fecha creación</th>
                      <th>Fecha ultima actualización</th>
                      <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody style="color:white">
                  @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
                    <tr>
                      <th>{{$project->id}}</th>
                      <td>{{$project->slug}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->order}}</td>
                      <td>{{$project->public}}</td>
                      <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($project->created_at))}}</td>
                      <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($project->updated_at))}}</td>
                      <td><a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">View</a> <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit</a>
                  @endforeach
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
  <br><br>
</div>  <!-- DIV TO LIST ALL THE PROJECTS END HERE -->

<div id="form1" style="display:none;" class="col-md-8"> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 START HERE-->
    <div>
    <h3>Crear nuevo proyecto</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="formcreateproject">
        <form  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm" name="myForm">
         <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label name="title">Slug:</label>
            <input type="text" id="slug" name="slug" placeholder="ejemplo-de-slug" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="order">Order:</label>
            <input type="number" id="order" name="order" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            <label name="public">Public:</label>
            <input type="number" id="public" name="public" class="form-control form-control-sm">
             <label name="body">Header</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathheader" id="pathheader"  class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>
            <label name="body">Home</label>
            <input type="file" name="pathhome" id="pathhome" class="form-control-file" aria-describedby="fileHelp"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Crear Proyecto" id="createprojectsubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
            <br><br><br>

          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
</div> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 END HERE-->

<div id="form2" style="display:none;" class="col-md-6"> 
  <div class="col-md-"> 
      <h3>Crear nueva traduccion</h3>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myFormTraduccion" name="myFormTraduccion"><!--FIRST FORM TO TRANSLATE -->
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label name="Language">Language:</label>
              <input type="text" id="locale" name="locale" value="en" disabled class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="Project">Project id:</label>
              <input type="number" id="project" name="project" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="Title">Title:</label>
              <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="Caption">Caption:</label>
              <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" class="form-control form-control-sm"><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Crear Traduccion" id="createtranslatesubmit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
              <br><br><br>

            </div>
          </form> <!-- FIRST FORM TO TRANSLATE END HERE -->
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myFormTraduccion2" name="myFormTraduccion2"> <!--SECOND FORM TO TRANSLATE -->
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label name="title">Language:</label>
              <input type="text" id="locale" name="locale" value="es" disabled class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="order">Project id:</label>
              <input type="number" id="project" name="project" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="public">Title:</label>
              <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control form-control-sm">
              <label name="caption">Caption:</label>
              <input type="text" id="caption" name="caption" class="form-control form-control-sm"><br>
              <input type="submit" value="Crear Traduccion" id="createtranslatesubmit2" class="btn btn-danger btn-md">
              <br><br><br>

            </div>
          </form>  <!--SECOND FORM TO TRANSLATE END HERE -->
  </div>
</div>
@stop
```

Div with **id="form"** works.

When i try to create the translate don't give me any error, but don't work correctly. As you can see the submit button have id *createtranslatesubmit* and the id of the form is *myFormTradducion*.
Here i put the ajax code:

```
//Javascript view /projects/menu.blade.php
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttoncreate").click(function(){
        $("#listall").hide();
        $("#form1").fadeIn(1000);

    });

    $("#createprojectsubmit").click(function(){
        $("#myForm").submit();
    });

    $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/projects/postUpload',
            type:'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(){
                $("#form1").fadeOut(1000);
                $("#form2").fadeIn(1000);
                $("#form3").fadeIn(1000);

            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
    });

    $("#createtranslatesubmit").click(function(){
        $("#myFormTraduccion").submit();
    });

    $("myFormTraduccion").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'/admin/projects/postUploadTranslation',
            type:'post',
            data:$('#myFormTraduccion').serializeArray(),
            success: function(){
                $("#form2").fadeOut(1000);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Routes are this:

```
 //Proyectos
    Route::get('project/listall', ['uses' => 'AdminController@listAll', 'as' => 'admin.projects.listall']);
    Route::get('project/create', ['uses' => 'AdminController@createProject', 'as' => 'admin.projects.formupload']);
    Route::post('projects/postUpload', ['uses' => 'AdminController@storeProject', 'as' => 'admin.projects.store']);
    **Route::post('projects/postUploadTranslation', ['uses' => 'Web\ProjectsTranslationController@storeTranslation', 'as' => 'admin.projectstranslation.store']);**
    Route::get('project/{id}/edit', ['uses' => 'AdminController@editProject', 'as' => 'admin.project.edit']);
    Route::put('projects/{id}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@updateProject', 'as' => 'admin.project.update']);
    Route::delete('project/{id}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@destroyProject', 'as' => 'admin.projects.destroy']);
    Route::get('project/{id}/delete', ['uses' => 'AdminController@delete', 'as' => 'admin.projects.delete']);
    Route::get('project/{id}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@showProject', 'as' => 'admin.projects.show']);
```

Controller is in a folder called Web, controller looks like here:

```
use App\Models\ProjectTranslation;
class ProjectsTranslationController extends Controller
{
        public function storeTranslation(Request $request)
        {
        $projecttranslation = new ProjectTranslation();
        $projecttranslation->locale = $request->input("locale");
        $projecttranslation->project_id = $request->input("project");
        $projecttranslation->title = $request->input("title");
        $projecttranslation->caption = $request->input("caption");
        $projecttranslation->save();
        }
}
```

So when i click on submit with id *createtranslatesubmit* url change and looks like this:

> http://test.loc/admin/projects?_token=ymzuWLO6I0nl7z5CQEriftjP1swWmH&project=40&title=1&caption=1

Know what's wrong?

If need more info, please ask it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: if you post it by for example with postman, can you dump the data? Or what errors are there?

Comment: @Bas Solved! thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot #

```
$("myFormTraduccion").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/admin/projects/postUploadTranslation',
        type:'post',
        data:$('#myFormTraduccion').serializeArray(),
        success: function(){
            $("#form2").fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Updated code:

```
$("#myFormTraduccion").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/admin/projects/postUploadTranslation',
        type:'post',
        data:$('#myFormTraduccion').serializeArray(),
        success: function(){
            $("#form2").fadeOut(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate! This fix the problem!

Answer (score 0):

try to clear the cache by below command in your project folder

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

then try again